# C# Regex bug with URL

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, url

I'm parsing a file of URL to get the host and URI part but there is a bug when the URL is not finished with a slash.

C# code :

```
var URL = Regex.Match(link, @"(?:.*?//)?(.*?)(/.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Input :

```
//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico
/opensearch.xml
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://careers.stackoverflow.com
```

Output :

```
//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico has 2 groups:
    cdn.sstatic.net
    /stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

/opensearch.xml has 2 groups:

    /opensearch.xml

http://stackoverflow.com/ has 2 groups:
    stackoverflow.com
    /
http://careers.stackoverflow.com has 2 groups:
    http:
    //careers.stackoverflow.com
```

Every URL in the output is valid exept for : http://careers.stackoverflow.com. How can I check for a variable part like "if there is a slash, stop to the first one orelse grab everythings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `|$` to your last group, to match that text or match the end of the expression.

This works for your inputs:

```
var links = new[]
    {
        "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
        "/opensearch.xml",
        "http://stackoverflow.com/",
        "http://careers.stackoverflow.com"
    };

foreach (string link in links)
{
    var u = Regex.Match(link, @"(?:.*?//)?(.*?)(/.*|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine(link);
    Console.WriteLine("    " + u.Groups[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("    " + u.Groups[2]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico
    cdn.sstatic.net
    /stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

/opensearch.xml

    /opensearch.xml

http://stackoverflow.com/
    stackoverflow.com
    /

http://careers.stackoverflow.com
    careers.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

```
/(?:.+\/\/|\/\/)?([^\/]*)(\/.+)?/
```

Answer (score -1):

usr is right that you should use the `Uri` class but if you insist on using `Regex`, try using the zero-width positive lookahead assertion like this:

```
var URL = Regex.Match(link, @"(?:.*?//)?(.*?(?=/|$))(/.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

More details at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion

Comment: `Uri` class won't work.  These are not valid Uris. Generates "System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Comment: The regex doesn't work either.  Still produces `http:` for group 1 and `//careers.stackoverflow.com` for group 2.